# sqlite3_open does not recognize URI Filename in C

Tags: c, sqlite, uri

I wrote this sample C code to open the database:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include "litereplica.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;
   char *uri ="file:/path-to-db/fuel_transaction_1.db";
   rc = sqlite3_open(uri, &db);

   if( rc ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return(0);
   }else{
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }   
   sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

When I compile and run this code, the output is `Can't open database: unable to open database file`.
I changed the `char *uri ="file:/path-to-db/fuel_transaction_1.db";` to this : `char *uri ="/path-to-db/fuel_transaction_1.db";` and it opened the database.

Could someone let me know why it does not recognize URI filename?

Thanks,

Comment: Try `"file://path-to-db/fuel_transaction_1.db";` (double `/`after `file:`. But does `sqlite3_open` accept an URI instead of a plain filename ? The doc doesn't say so.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but It didn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** if you want to have URI support you have to compile your sqlite with SQLITE_USE_URI=1 or use this line to open your DB.

```
rc = sqlite3_open_v2(uri, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_URI, NULL);
```

From [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/uri.html#backwards_compatibility):

> Backwards Compatibility
>
> In order to maintain full backwards compatibility for legacy applications, the URI filename capability is disabled by default. URI filenames can be enabled or disabled using the SQLITE_USE_URI=1 or SQLITE_USE_URI=0 compile-time options. The compile-time setting for URI filenames can be changed at start-time using the sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_URI,1) or sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_URI,0) configuration calls. Regardless of the compile-time or start-time settings, URI filenames can be enabled for individual database connections by including the SQLITE_OPEN_URI bit in the set of bits passed as the F parameter to sqlite3_open_v2(N,P,F,V).
>
> If URI filenames are recognized when the database connection is originally opened, then URI filenames will also be recognized on ATTACH statements. Similarly, if URI filenames are not recognized when the database connection is first opened, they will not be recognized by ATTACH.
>
> Since SQLite always interprets any filename that does not begin with "`file:`" as an ordinary filename regardless of the URI setting, and because it is very unusual to have an actual file begin with "`file:`", it is safe for most applications to enable URI processing even if URI filenames are not currently being used.

try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include "litereplica.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;
   char *uri ="file:/path-to-db/fuel_transaction_1.db";

   rc = sqlite3_open_v2(uri, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_URI, NULL);

   //rc = sqlite3_open(uri, &db);

   if( rc ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return(0);
   }else{
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }   
   sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. actually I don't know where and how should I add `SQLITE_USE_URI=1`.

Comment: You use SQLITE_USE_URI=1 if you compile SQLITE yourself otherwise you can change this setting at runtime with this command: sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_URI,1)

Comment: @Marco, I also tried adding `sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_URI,1)`; , but still the output is `Can't open database: unable to open database file`

Comment: @MichaelWalz: tnx for the comment. I don't know where I should write the uri in `sqlite3_open_v2(dbname, &db, SQLITE_USE_URI=1, NULL);`

Comment: @mOna The [`documentation`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) is clear enough, isn't it ?`

Comment: @MichaelWalz: no, honestly I read the documentation even before I post my question, but still didn't understand it well :| I tried `sqlite3_open_v2(uri, &db, SQLITE_USE_URI=1, NULL);` instead of `sqlite3_open` in my code, but now I get this error: `error: ‘SQLITE_USE_URI’ undeclared (first use in this function)`

Comment: rc = sqlite3_open_v2(uri, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_URI, NULL);